# Sum elements in stream while taking max (0,x)?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have a `List<Double>` such as [2,4.3,-1.1]. I want to sum these elements, while removing all of the negative numbers (I'm thinking to take the max of each number vs 0). For this example, the answer should be 2 + 4.3 = 6.3

I want to use Java 8 streams to do this, but I'm stuck in getting the max (x,0) part down. Does anyone have any clue to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
scores.stream()
      .mapToDouble(i -> i.getValue())
      // max between the number and 0??
      .sum
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.mapToDouble(i -> Math.max(i, 0))
```

You could also do this with a filter:

```
.filter(i -> i > 0)
```